# How does Bitlocker interfere with a dual-boot system?

Tags: multi-boot, bitlocker

I have a netbook running Windows 7 Ultimate. I am thinking of configuring Bitlocker on it. The computer does not currently have anything installed but Windows. (I removed a HP service partition.)

If I install Bitlocker, what effects will this have on my ability to install another OS like Linux, FreeBSD, or eComStation 2.0?

Comment: http://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=4896

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. The bootmgr can be modified to dual boot into other OSes.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/voy/archive/2006/10/13/building-a-dual-boot-system-with-windows-vista-bitlocker-protection-with-tpm-support.aspx